# redefine \( \) to mean \begin{equation} \end{equation}

Tags: macros, equations, environments

I *never* use `\(` `\)`.  How do I redefine them to mean `\begin{equation}` `\end{equation}`?

(I know that many of you will think this is a bad idea.)

Comment: It _is_ a bad idea! `\DeclareRobustCommand\({\begin{equation}}` and the equivalent for the `\end` part should do... (you could also do with `\def\({\begin{equation}}`; I used `\DeclareRobustCommand` to keep the definition robust, as the original.)

Comment: Ha, I hadn't clued in that a simple construct like that would in fact work.  Frame it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I think it is rather an editor problem, to be configured so that with a shortcut it displays `begin{equation}  \end{equation}` and the cursor in-between.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Don't!

---

If you do, don't blame me ;-)

TeX macros can (under normal circumstances, no `\csname`, not `\catcode` involved) be of two basic types: control sequences and control characters. A control sequence is formed by an escape character (normally `\`) followed by a sequence of "letter" tokens (normally `a-z` and `A-Z`), for example `\begin`. A control character is formed by an escape character and one single non-letter token (every other character that doesn't fit as "letter"). TeX allows you to define/access both control sequences and control characters in the same way, so `\def\mymacro{something}` is as valid as `\def\({something}`.

In `latex.ltx`, `\(` and `\)` are defined as:

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand\({%
  \relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\){%
  \relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}%
```

The extra code checks for nested usage of `\(...\)`, which is invalid. You can replace `$` by the proper environment delimiters (and move the `\end{equation}` to the `\else` branch of `\ifinner`):

```latex
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\({%
  \relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else\begin{equation}\fi}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\){%
  \relax\ifmmode\ifinner\@badmath\else\end{equation}\fi\else\@badmath\fi}%
\makeatother
```

As egreg said in the comment below, if you load `amsmath` (which you usually should), then you can leave the nesting check to `equation`:

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand\({\begin{equation}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\){\end{equation}}
```

Comment: I somehow feel like the "Don't" should be _much_ larger. ;-)

Comment: In `amsmath.sty` (that should be used for any document containing an `equation` environment) we read `\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}` and `\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}`. No need to add the checks, because `\begin{equation}` already takes care of them. But of course I agree with ***DON'T***. `:-)`

Comment: @schtandard There :-) I was trying to be not _too_ shouty

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I knew I was forgetting something slightly important :-)